# How to fix Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult' to 'string'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

return View(viewModel); cause error in visual studio 2008

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult' to 'string'

```
public ActionResult Welcome(string name, int numTimes = 1)
        {
            var viewModel = new WelcomeViewModel
            {
                Message = "Hello " + name,
                NumTimes = numTimes
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        public class WelcomeViewModel
        {
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public int NumTimes { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us which line causes this error, instead of making us guess?

Comment: Hmm... are you sure that `Welcome` is declared as you've indicated?  Can you paste the entire class definition that contains `Welcome`?

Comment: Yep - that code should work. Your hiding something you stealthy ninja you.

Comment: Do you have View Welcome.cshtml (or .aspx) in folder /Views/{Controller}/?

Comment: It could be an error within the view markup maybe?  That code looks good.

Comment: Quoting OP: "I discover i haven't return a ActionResult so cause error, thanks". The code in question doesn't reflect the actual problem, and in-fact there's no problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to append .ToString() to the method call where ever you are calling it, although this will not return the expected result in most cases.  Instead I would make another Welcome method that returns a String and do what you need to within that method.

Comment: Thanks. I discover i haven't return a ActionResult so cause error, thanks.

Comment: Following my first MVC tutorial led me here, thus I believe this is still a common mistake to make. You should mark this as solved and post the appropiate answer. This last comment (that helped me solve the problem) is a little hard to find.

Comment: What @CarlosGarcia is missing to state is that the return type of the given method should be ActionResult and not string. This error is caused when people are following a tutorial and try to implement a controller, that passes a model to the view.